# Put more than one expression in an arrow function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have data returned from an http.get (function in a service)

```
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').toPromise().then(
  response => response.json().results as User[]
).catch(this.handleError);
```

In the component I call this service and set my model to the json result

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userService.getUser().then(
    users => this.users = users
  );
}
```

In the template I can just use `{{user.email}}` to get the email.

Now if I try to add a line of code inside the http promise.then

```
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').toPromise().then(
  response =>  {
    response.json().results as User[];
    console.log(response);
  }
).catch(this.handleError);
```

The console show the response object, but user.email is not displayed in the page anymore. (no error in the consoles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions either take a single expression, and implicitly return the result, or a series of statements, with no implicit return. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) on arrow functions for more detail. To fix this, you need to explicitly return `response.json().results` at the end of your arrow function:

```
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').toPromise().then(
  response =>  {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json().results as User[];
  }
).catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **`return`** statement

```
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/').toPromise().then(
  //response =>  {
  //  response.json().results as User[];
  //  console.log(response);
  //}
  response =>  {
    console.log(response);
    // we have to return something here
    return response.json().results as User[];
  }
).catch(this.handleError);
```